# Settings for ctag in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I have installed Notepad++ on Windows 7 machine. And have installed "Gtag Search" plugin for browsing through the code using ctags.

As mentioned in the plugin page, have put the gtags and ctags executables in notepad++\plugins\gtagfornplus directory and have set the PATH environment variable accordingly.

Also have created tags file in my code project and have placed them @ C:\ too.

Now when i go to Plugin->Gtag Search->Find Definition, Gtag Search window opens but do not show any result.

Could any one please comment what step i have missed.

Also, where Gtag Search plugin expect the tags file to be?

Answer (score 2):

you should check this: [gtags](http://gtagfornplus.sourceforge.net/)  or install nppgtag plugin in notepad++

Comment: +1 for nppgtag. Was having the same problem using gtag. nppgtag regenerated the database and everything is working great.